# Is it possible to search full-text on PDF with Azure Search?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-cognitive-search

I am new to the Microsoft Cognitive Services. I'm trying to create a Search Bot which looks into 2 PDF files stored as BLOB in Azure Storage. If the user ask a question like "How can I make a flexrequest?", it will look into the PDF files and answer to the user.
The problem is, both files contains keywords 'flexrequest'.

I like to know how I can look into pdf with Azure Search on a keyword. I already followed the tutorial on the documentation with no success. It only look for the title of the document and returns the WHOLE document. I only need a specific part of the text.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to query the document body and return a snippet of the text.  However, you'll need to make sure that your document body field is both searchable and retrievable.

Once your index is configured correctly, you can query across all searchable fields within the same index. I'm not sure what your actual index looks like, but based on your description I created a sample below that should query for the term in the title and document and return document fragments containing the term in the highlight response.
GET /indexes/yourIndexHere/docs?search=flexrequest&searchFields=document,title&highlight=document&api-version=2017-11-11

I'd also suggest that you take a look at QnA Maker which (also uses Azure Search) and is designed to support exactly these kind of scenarios.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/qna-maker/

Comment: @Brain, can you please provide link/example as how to query the document body and return a snippet of the text?